# IIS in VirtualBox serving files from shared Ubuntu folder

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6

Here's the problem:

- I want to use Ubuntu.
- But I need to develop ASP.NET (MVC) sites.
- So I setup VirtualBox with Win2003 and IIS6.
- But I would prefer my working files to be located in my Ubuntu home folder.
- So I setup shared folder in VirtualBox and make IIS6 virtual directory work from there.

The problem is, IIS6 can't do this. Whatever I try (mapped drive, network uri path) I get different IIS errors: can't access folder (for mapped drive), can't monitor file system changes (\vboxsvr share path), and so on.

Is there a way for IIS6 in virtual machine to configure virtual application folder to be on host machine (Ubuntu) - be it shared folder, mapped drive, smb share, or whatever?

Here's what I got using mapped drive:

> HttpException (0x80004005): Server
>   cannot access application directory
>   'h:\work\web\'. The directory does not
>   exist or is not accessible because of
>   security settings.]

And this is using network share path option in IIS:

> [HttpException (0x80070001): Failed to
>   start monitoring changes to
>   '\vboxsvr\queen3\work\web

UPDATE: also, to avoid "Failed to start monitoring changes" one may consider [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911272) method (disable ASP.NET monitoring file changes). This will allow to use VirtualBox shared folders, not only samba shares. This also helps to debug apps from Visual Studio using run (F5), only solution has to be open from share, not mapped file (\vboxsvr\share).

Comment: Permissions on the share perhaps?

Comment: OK, where do I setup permissions on VirtualBox shared folder?

Comment: Note that I can use this share, write files and build solution using Visual Studio. But IIS can't.

Comment: I'm finding some hits, start here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257174

Comment: and http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AccessingMappedNetworkDrivesViaASPNETInIIS6.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be an issue with how virtualbox is sharing the folder using the special vboxsvr name. Try sharing the folder on Ubuntu using Samba and then mapping it in the virtual machine using the IP address instead.

Comment: I get the same 0x80004005 directory access exception when using mapped drive for smb share on Ubuntu. However if I configure IIS to use share path (\\ubuntu\share) I can get past my errors and get "PolicyException: Required permissions cannot be acquired" - which is a step further, thanks. The policy exception is probably about full trust since the assemblies are on network share...

Comment: That's right, this link http://marcoscavaleiro.blogspot.com/2006/11/failed-to-grant-minimum-permission.html helped me to avoid PolicyException. Now I get SecurityException about partially trusted callers, oh boy ;-) But that's a different story. In short SMB share worked. I wonder if VBox share can be setup this way or this was because of Ubuntu access rights to home folder...

Comment: would be greate if you post your smb.conf, or the important sections,